# MASM GetTempPath and writing to registry - squares?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to get the Windows temppath and write it to the registry, but all I get in the registry are squares ?

Code:

```
tmpFilePath db 256 dup(?)
```

Get temp path

```
main PROC
     invoke GetTempPath, 255,addr tmpFilePath`
```

Write to registry

```
WriteReg PROC 

    invoke RegCreateKeyExW,HKEY_CURRENT_USER,offset regkey,NULL,NULL,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL,offset hIDKey,NULL

    .IF eax==ERROR_SUCCESS
        invoke lstrlenW,offset tmpFilePath
        add eax,eax
        add eax,2
        invoke RegSetValueExW,hIDKey,offset keyname,NULL,REG_SZ,offset buf,eax
        invoke RegCloseKey,hIDKey
```

Comment: For starters, you may want to use GetTempPathW.

Comment: And then it magically worked, if you could post this as answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GetTempPathW in order to get a file name that is compatible with RegCreateKeyExW.